# How to resign keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift3, ios10, resignfirstresponder

I have made a small program which I use to count the money in the safe at work, but after updating my iPhone, it didn't work anymore.

After a lot of reading and so on I fixed everything, but I haven't found a new way to resign the keyboard.

Before the update I used this:

```
@IBAction func resignKeyboard(_sender: AnyObject) {
    _sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This doesn't work anymore so I would love a new way of doing it. I have searched quite a bit for a solution, but I haven't understood any of the solutions I have found. So please simplify your answers as a lot as possible.

This is everything from the "ViewController.Swift" from my program:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Pengeskabstæller
//
//  Created by Alex on 09/07/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Alex. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var In50B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In50L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In20B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In20L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In10B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In10L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In5B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In5L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In2B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In2L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In1B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In1L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In05B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var In05L: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Ialt: UILabel!


@IBAction func resignKeyboard(_sender: AnyObject) {
    _sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Knap(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Hvad knappen gør

    //Ganger input ved værdi af bundt eller løse
    var x50B: Int = Int(In50B.text!)!
    x50B = x50B*5000
    var x50L:Int = Int(In50L.text!)!
    x50L = x50L*500
    var x20B:Int = Int(In20B.text!)!
    x20B = x20B*4000
    var x20L:Int = Int(In20L.text!)!
    x20L = x20L*400
    var x10B:Int = Int(In10B.text!)!
    x10B = x10B*2000
    var x10L:Int = Int(In10L.text!)!
    x10L = x10L*200
    var x5B:Int = Int(In5B.text!)!
    x5B = x5B*1000
    var x5L:Int = Int(In5L.text!)!
    x5L = x5L*200
    var x2B:Int = Int(In2B.text!)!
    x2B = x2B*500
    var x2L:Int = Int(In2L.text!)!
    x2L = x2L*50
    var x1B:Int = Int(In1B.text!)!
    x1B = x1B*500
    var x1L:Int = Int(In1L.text!)!
    x1L = x1L*50
    var x05B:Int = Int(In05B.text!)!
    x05B = x05B*200
    var x05L:Int = Int(In05L.text!)!
    x05L = x05L*20

    //Lægger det hele sammen

    let penge1 = (x50B + x50L + x20B)
    let penge2 = (x20L + x10B + x10L)
    let penge3 = (x5B + x5L + x2B + x2L)
    let penge4 = (x1B + x1L + x05B + x05L)
    let penge99 = String(penge1+penge2+penge3+penge4)

    //Printer ialt
    Ialt.text = penge99
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a better way to do it, instead of adding an outlet.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works perfectly! But I'm having the next problem, it crashes when I press the button which activates the last bit of the app.

Comment: Is that happening after you added this bit of code? That wouldn't make much sense. Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Nope the problem was something else which changed between swift 2 and 3. I got it fixed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324555/my-app-is-simple-app-is-crashing/40324682#40324682

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all textFields are subviews of `view`, you can use [endEditing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting) method like this:

```
@IBAction func resignKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the sender to `UITextField` instead of `AnyObject` and then you can do `sender.resignFirstResponder()`